# Bevel in Blender Vs the Same bevel in Maya

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel on top of an existing bevel in blender. Blender can not figure out the curvature and breaks the mesh. The left is when I attempted the bevel in blender and on the right the bevel is done in Maya. any ideas why maya can bevel correctly and blender can't?

[image: Blender Bevel vs Maya]

This is the edge I try to bevel:

[image]

Comment: Hello, that's weird, could you please share just this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I uploaded it to my google drive. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13m49ubYXR85t0Tf3iDhgyJn7P2RNPwae/view?usp=sharing   thank you for your help

Comment: it looks like bad calculation, if I flatten the face on a custom transform orientation it will work fine

Comment: I have a lot faces at angles on this mesh. So I have just been beveling them in Maya with no problem then importing back in blender. I just have no idea why maya can figure it out at the angle that it is at and blender can not...

Comment: I know it happens with some bevels but I can't tell why, I hope someone will

Answer (score 3):

I'm willing to bet it has to do with the respective n-gon solver backend in Maya and Blender. N-gons only exist for the convenience of the 3D modeler in the application, but under the hood everything is converted to triangles.

This algorigthm might be having some kind of hiccup with this exact n-gon and causing issues.

[image]

Whenever I see issues crop up like this I usually try to take the guesswork out of the equation for the algorithm and manually triangulate it in a way that I know will work best for the bevel operation.

Usually something like this works best.

[image]

Comment: I was going to take this into Zbrush later to add details so I usually model in quads. do you know of any bevel add-ons for blender ? Maya bevels just have more options like mitering and mitering along which helps me get the exact bevels I want. I do want to make a full switch to blender but it's times like these that I have to go back and forth. I noticed if I bevel this edge first and then bevel the corners the mesh won't have as much issues. and I use Unf*ck to fix it. I do wish there were more bevel options

Comment: Blender definitely has a ton of options to fiddle with in it's built in bevel modifier, I don't think that this requires downloading a separate addon. I'm don't really understand the issue with this solution, you say you only model in quads, but the apparent reason for this issue comes from that fact that you have a giant n-gon in your base mesh. So which is it? When an issue like this pops up, triangulate manually to get around the issues, then if you find you have to retopo it then do so when that time comes. Are you not just going to zremesh it the second it get's into Zbrush anyways?

Comment: I mean have you tried using an actual non-destructive bevel modifier, rather than the destructive bevel tool? That definitely has Maya beat in that at least you can mess with it after the fact and tweak it to get the final result you want, all without manipulating the actual basemesh. Maya, it's just one and done you bevel it and there's no going back, without saving a copy of the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

@Jakenmoyo [seems to be onto it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269326/35559), so no credit here, please. This is just to suggest the forced triangulation may not need to be done by hand. It can possibly be done with a *Triangulate* modifier, as can the subsequent *Bevel*.

[image]

If 'Loop Slide' is unchecked, there seems to be no undesirable self-intersection where triangulation is tight, as in the bottom left corner of this object.

The modifer(s) could be copied between multiple objects, and/or a selective bevel set by weight, rather than angle.